# Function to sum elements in linked list not working

Tags: python

I have this linked list that has its numbers backwards (meaning the first element of the linked list is the last number to the right of the written number and so forth)

```
head = ListNode(5)
head.next = ListNode(4)


def sum_number(l1):
            n_sum = 0
            counter = 0
            while l1:
                n_sum += l1.val * (10^counter)
                l1 = l1.next
                counter += 1
            return n_sum
        
            
sum_number(head)
```

When I tried the previous code, the sum gave me 91. When I tried it with head = ListNode(5) alone, the answer was 50. I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: What are you expecting, 45? Also, show class `ListNode`.

Comment: Be aware that the "power" operator in Python is `**`, not `^`.

Comment: Were you intending to use `^` as a bit operator or did you mean to use it in the mathematical notation sense of power? If the latter, you would want to do `10**counter` instead. If you were intending it as a bitwise operator, than that output is expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer**

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

head = ListNode(5)
head.next = ListNode(4)

def sum_number(node):
    n_sum = 0
    counter = 0
    while node:
        n_sum += node.val * (10 ** counter)
        node = node.next
        counter += 1
    return n_sum

sum_number(head)
```

Output: `45`

**Explanation**

As @MichaelButscher mentioned in the OP comments, the problem is with the power operator (`**` in Python).

Comment: There's no problem with `next` as an attribute colliding with the builtin function `next`. `next` is not a method used by iterators any more. Since Python 3, the method is named `__next__`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Blckknght ! I was not aware. Editing the answer accordingly. (Too bad the syntax highlighter still considers it as a predefined function :))